# VSTS setting up CI for ASP.NET Core 2 application

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to build an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application using Visual Studio Team Services.  I have setup a build using the .NET Core tasks (2.* version).  Very basic setup just .NET Core Restore, .NET Core Build, .NET Core Test, Publish Test Results, .NET Core Publish and Publish Artifact.

When I start the build it is error on the Restore step.
First I get a warning that says

```
2017-09-20T17:25:02.3384534Z ##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: NGCommon_NoSourcesFoundInConfig
2017-09-20T17:25:02.3384534Z ##[warning]NGCommon_NoSourcesFoundInConfig d:\a\1\Nuget\tempNuGet_1110.config
```

Then I get an error that says

```
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
error NU1100: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (>= 2.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'.
```

I tried adding a .NET Core Tools Installer step to download version 2.0.0, but continued to get the same error.

I also tried a Nuget Tool Installer to pull in a newer version of nuget that I read somewhere was needed, but that didn't work either.

What do I need to do to Build an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project in VSTS.

**Edit**
I have redone the build with debug = true and also copied the project over to OneDrive both can be found here (https://oceanspray-my.sharepoint.com/personal/pcavacas_oceanspray_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?folderid=0dda9fd96603e4eaaa51d605029fa47f1&authkey=Ad36W5fWf0-J7QN6uIPexXg&expiration=2017-09-30T04%3a00%3a00.000Z).  At the root of that location is a file Build Log.txt, which contains the log from the Restore section.  There is also a folder which contains the whole project.

Comment: Since Hosted VS2017 agent has installed .NET Core 2.0.0, it's ok to build on Hosted VS2017 agent (or private agent you installed .net core 2.0). And I can build successful with .net core web API project (with .net core 2.0 as target framework). Can you show the detail logs by setting `system.debug` as `true` or can you upload your project to one drive?

Comment: I can also build your project successful with Hosted VS2017 agent, and this is my build log https://1drv.ms/t/s!ApIKkY1MTjMRgmjQ9vX0UzelsiSt. The main difference seems that it can't find where is download the sources in your build log (1052th line, that the OutputSources is empty). What if you specify the nuget.config (with `<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />`)  in .NET Core restore task and check if it can find the place where to download packages?

Comment: I have it working now thanks to your suggestions, so you can submit that as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Glad to hear your problem has been solved, and I posted the solution as answer now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hosted VS2017 agent has already installed .net core 2.0, so it’s ok to queue the asp.net core 2.0 project with Hosted VS2017 agent.

Based on your log, it seems it does not specified where to download the packages in your project level `nuget.config` file. So you can add the content in your `nuget.config` file:

```
<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
```

And specify the path of your `nugget.config` in .NET Core restore task, then the nugget packages should be restored successful.